# Row-wise intensiveness histogram

Tags: opencv, image-processing, histogram, emgucv

The idea is to identify the darkest rows of grayscale image. I have two options:

**Option 1: manual calculation**

I can calculate row-wise intensiveness of pixels manually, but I can't properly construct DenseHistogram object. Size of bins is equal to number of rows, the ranges are between 0 and 255, but I don't understand how to set those manually calculated values to the histogram?

**Option 2: DenseHistogram.Calculate**

My DenseHistogram object is calculating occurences of each intensity in whole image. How to instruct DenseHistogram to calculate intensity row-wise?

Please, see the picture attached. I want to have similar histogram in the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [cv::reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce) with CV_REDUCE_SUM or CV_REDUCE_AVG flag.